# Electric field in wire

Tags: electricity, electric-fields, electrical-resistance

in a wire with current :
$$
R = \int_a^b E dl / \int_\ ^\ j ds\
$$
$$ R=EL/jA
$$

Why **E** consider to be constant. even if I say **V** is constant between **a,b** can not assume **E** is constant , it is constant to **t** not to **L**

Answer (score 1):

If the cross sectional area of your wire is constant, then j and E will be constant (assuming uniform resistivity).